# How do you retrieve data from an external api in a wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am creating a plugin in wordpress that will create custom posts based on data that is received from an api. At first I had this code:

```
    $stuff_request    = 'https://thisdomain/api/stuff';
    $username = 'thisdomainuser';
    $password = 'thisdomainpassword';

  $headers = array( 'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( "$username:$password" ) );
  $stuff_response = wp_remote_get( $stuff_request, array( 'headers' => $headers ));

  $stuff_data = json_decode($stuff_response, true);
```

but I was receiving the error
"expects paremter 1 to be string array given"
which suggested to me that $stuff_response might already be getting returned in the correct format so I removed the json_decode from season data

```
    $stuff_data = $stuff_response;
```

but this fails to return anything at all and no error messages appear in debug. Is this a problem with how I am calling the api into the plugin or could it be an issue with the external api?

Comment: `var_dump($stuff_response);`

Comment: or print_r($stuff_response);

Comment: thanks have added this to my plugin, and I am returning null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response that comes back from `wp_remote_get` is an array.

Try this:

```
$stuff_request    = 'https://thisdomain/api/stuff';
$username = 'thisdomainuser';
$password = 'thisdomainpassword';

$headers = array( 'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( "$username:$password" ) );
$stuff_response = wp_remote_get( $stuff_request, array( 'headers' => $headers));
if( is_array($stuff_response ) ) {

  $header = $stuff_response['headers']; // array of http header lines
  $body = json_decode( $stuff_response['body'] ); // use the content

}
```

Comment: thanks, I have updated my code to match the above and used the suggested var_dump above and I find that I am returning a null, any thoughts?

Comment: `var_dump($body);` returns null?

Comment: yes, does this mean it's a problem with the json I am trying to bring in? because I believe the call is now correct?

Comment: Try adding this right after the `wp_remote_get` call: `if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
   $error_string = $result->get_error_message();
   echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p>' . $error_string . '</p></div>';
}`. That should let us know if there is an error. Otherwise, if that is clear, than it is most likely a problem on the other server, or an authorization issue.

Comment: the message that comes up when you activate the plugin is "The plugin generated 147 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin"

Comment: the fix for this was to add 'sslverify' => false into the remote get request array. many thanks for all the help with the code and sorry for the delayed reply.